# Swift App does not see JSON data - use of unresolved identifier

Tags: json, swift, import, xcode11

I am following the Apple Developer Tutorials to learn swift programming. When I try to implement an animation taught in their tutorial [here](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/animating-views-and-transitions), I cannot add the JSON data to my project directory properly, hence I cannot produce previews.

My project structure is:

Hiking

- Hike,swift
- HikeView.swift
- HikeGraph.swift
- HikeDetail.swift
- GraphCapsule.swift
- Resources/

  - hikeData.json

However, I get the error mentioned in the title, use of unresolved identifier. I did another project by again following Apple tutorial and JSON data was inside a folder named Resources, and it is working. How should I import the JSON file, hikeData.json?

Edit:

This JSON file is used as follows:

```
HikeDetail(hike: hikeData[0])
```

Comment: check if its present in copy bundle resources ? in `target -> build phases -> copy bundle resources`

Comment: @jawadAli where is this target option?

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you target is checked against that file

[image]

Then check if it present here

[image]

Comment: I edited the question, and checked your comment above.